Explanation of OpenCV tracking algorithms?
i'm using OpenCV for a school project using OpenCV for some object tracking. I know that there are multiple tracker in OpenCV, but can someone explain roughly how a tracker algorithm works in this case. And is it possible to code a primal version of that ? (not using blackbox like these trackers would be better for my project).
Thank you all (you can go a bit deeper in the explanation, and can add some mathematicals aspect)
I'm trying to code a simple object tracking in python but I want to do most of the job myself or at least comprehend what i'm using. In my code i'm using OpenCV but the tracker part make me a bit worried.

that's a very broad question, and you're asking others to do the research. to learn about all the different approaches to object tracking, it takes a college-level lecture or big chapter of a textbook. please review [ask] and [help/on-topic]/[help/dont-ask] you could also start by consulting ChatGPT or other AI models, if you're not comfortable with a regular search engine.

If you want to make a simple handcraft object tracking, you can make color-based object tracking. It is white box approach.

Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
